# Working from EU country for a few days as non EU citizen on a German Blue Card

Tags: eu, blue-card

I am a non-EU citizen working in Germany. I got a Blue Card a few months ago. Can I work from France remotely (for the same company) for 7 days knowing that my company allows it. Officially, am I allowed to do this?

Comment: Not really but I don't think you would risk much.